# I see default apache page and not Luma site

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

After installing Magento2 I see the default page of Apache 2 and not that of Luma site. What could be the problem? Thanks so much for the support

Comment: There could be multiple reasons, check your apache configuration file and/or vhost if configured. Check your domain name in core_config_data. To get a better help on this please post your apache config file and Magento configuration. Last thing check if your cookie/cookie domain is holding old value if yes then you need to remove it. Thanks

Comment: Hi I checked the hosts file. I cleared the cache, changed the nginx/sites-avaible folder but it still doesn't work. I only see the default apache page.

Comment: I assume you installed magento in your host server. In this case `check the document root of your domain and confirm whether its the magento_root directory`. Also `check your magento instance deployment mode`, by default its in default mode, `change it to developer mode` if its your development instance for easier debugging.